# Cannot install mysql-server-5.5/the following packages have unmet dependencies

Tags: apt, mysql

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

I tried entering `mysql` with the following command:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

and I got the following message:

The program `mysql` can be found on the following packages:

- `mysql-client-core-5.5`
- `mariadb-client-core-5.5`
- `mysql-client-core-5.6`
- `percona-xtrabd-cluster-client-5.5`

I then typed in:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-client-core-5.6
```

After this was installed, I tried connecting to `mysql` again using:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

I then got the error message:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

After searching online, I found out I needed to install `mysql` server and so I wrote in the following command

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

I then got the message ;

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.5 but it is not going to be installed
 E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I've been looking on line for the past hour for a solution, but other people who had a similar error but had it from upgrading `mysql` and thus there solution were ineffective for me.

Comment: Add the output of `sudo apt-get check` and `apt-cache policy mysql-server mysql-server-5.5`

Comment: Here is the solution that worked for me.

http://askubuntu.com/questions/489815/cannot-install-mysql-server-5-5-the-following-packages-have-unmet-dependicies/489817#489817

Answer (score 2):

The reason of your problem is probably that you are trying to mix different versions of mysql.

You have `mysql-client-core-5.6` and are now trying to install `mysql-server-5.5`.

So what do you want 5.5 or 5.6?

Either remove `mysql-client-core-5.6` (and any other mysql-5.6 package which might be installed) and install `mysql-client-core-5.5` instead. Then you should be able to install `mysql-server` (which depends on `mysql-server-5.5`)

OR

Try to install `mysql-server-5.6` instead of `mysql-server`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install

> mysql-server and mysql-shared

Packages

Answer (score 0):

[This other unix.stackexchange answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/58293/79059) solved my issue with:

```
sudo aptitude install mysql-server
```

Aptitude might tell you you have to uninstall mysql-server, but then you should be able to re-install it to fix the un-met dependency.

However, I am not sure installation is your problem. `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)` might mean that mysql isn't running. So before you un/install anything try:

```
/etc/init.d/mysql start
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

`mkdir /var/run/mysqld`

`touch /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`

`chown -R mysql /var/run/mysqld`

`/etc/init.d/mysql restart`